# Am using Python Django and I want to validate a NVarchar variable

Tags: python, html, django, href, nvarchar

I want to validate the 1st letter of the NVarchar and identify if it starts with **'P' or 'I'** and then respectively switch between *href* tags.

[This is the **jobseqno** from DB][1]
[This is the actual condition that i want to modify][2]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PqtWc.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UgnFW.jpg

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: Please post your code and not Images.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built-in filter called `first`.

```
{% if jobseqno|first == 'P' %}
    <a href="{{ xsite_wo_report_url }}{{ jobseqno }}">{{ jobseqno }}</a>
{% else %}
    <a href="{{ xsite_wr_report_url }}{{ jobseqno }}">{{ jobseqno }}</a>
{% endif %}
```